# Web logging with Response.Redirect

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We have a logging framework for our MVC applications that uses a HttpModule.  Among other functions, we use it to time the response time of the request.

We initialize it by attaching the PostAcquireRequestState to start timing.  We attach to PostRequestHandlerExecute stop timing and log to database.  See below for our initialization logic.

```
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PostAcquireRequestState += OnBeginRequest;
        context.PostRequestHandlerExecute += LogRequest;

    }
```

For ASP.Net MVC, this works great.

We are trying to adapt this to our legacy WebForms applications.  These two events work correctly, except when a Response.Redirect() function is called.  In searching multiple web pages about page life cycle, I cannot find information about what event is thrown after Response.Redirect has executed.

Comment: I'm not sure there's any event unless you do `Response.Redirect("url", false)` because it will throw a `ThreadAbortException`.

Comment: That is a step that I'm trying to avoid.  Doing this will require requiring source code updates to a 3 very large web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further experimentation, I found that I could use the EndRequest event.

```
        context.PostAcquireRequestState += OnBeginRequest;
        context.EndRequest += LogRequest;
```